# Laravel: How to handle optional data in a form request?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blade that under certain conditions shows Form1 and other conditions will show Form2.  In Form1, the only field available is `description` and that is what is getting updated. In Form2, the `message` field is the only one available and that is what gets edited.
How would I handle this in the Form request file?
I was think of making them `nullable` like this:

```
return [
    'message'       => 'nullable',
    'description'   => 'nullable'
];
```

But I want the `description` field to be required when Form1 is used and `message` to be required when Form2 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional validation in your controller, similar to this:

```
   if( form 1 is sumbitted ) {
     $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'message' => 'required|string'
    ]);
   }
   elseif( form 2 is submitted ) {
     $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'description' => 'required|string'
    ]);
   }
```